# Installing Ubuntu desktop on Ubuntu production web server

Tags: webserver, apache2, vnc

I have a AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server with LAMP stack (Apache2, MySQL-Client (Database is on different DB server), PHP) which will be used as production web server. Till now I had been using the terminal over ssh via putty to do all the installation and configuration.

I am just thinking to install ubuntu-desktop and vnc-server to access desktop via vnc.

Questions:

1. Does installing ubuntu-desktop convert my server to a desktop instance of ubuntu? I definitely do not want to do that.
2. Will installing these additional software overload the servers performance? I know there will be some resource requirement to run these software as well but it cannot be substantial.
3. The advantage of having a desktop I think is, It is easier to install and maintain the web server and its components.
4. Right now I access my server using a ssh private key over putty, can I access VNC similarly, if yes how?

Thanks

Karmendra

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.
Although I don't think it will be very useful as you will still need to do most of the configuration through terminal and text-based files.

Good riddance.